# Is it possible to read property file values inside @Repository?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, properties, repository

Is it possible to read property file values inside `@Repository`.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No different as in an `@Service`, `@Controller` or whichever `@Component`.

Comment: I have tried the same but for @Repository
public interface TransferMessageRepository extends JpaRepository<TransferMessage, Long> {

 @Value("${spring.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size}")
 String abcd; But this is giving the error like the variable may or may not been initialised

Comment: Now that is something you didn't state and is a whole different question. No that won't work.

Comment: Do we have a solution for this?

Comment: Don't do it as it won't work. If you want to set the fetch size, configure hibernate don't do it per query.

Comment: Any way to get property values inside an interface

Comment: No there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

As M.Deinum mentioned in the comment section, `@Repository` is just a variation of `@Component`. You can read your property file by injecting `Environment` or you can just use `@Value`.

Comment: I have tried the same but for @Repository
public interface TransferMessageRepository extends JpaRepository<TransferMessage, Long> {

 @Value("${spring.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size}")
 String abcd; But this is giving the error like the variable may or may not been initialised

Answer (score 1):

If you use a class repository, you can use the `@Value` annotation on any non-final field to have it populated automatically.

On the other hand, if you are using an interface repository, you cannot read a property directly, as you have nowhere to inject your components/values.

Anyway, I found a sort of work-around which can be used to achieve a similar result.

You start by creating a class that implements `ApplicationContextProvider`:

```
@Component
public class StaticPropertiesProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(@Nonnull final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        StaticPropertiesProvider.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getProperty(final String property, final Class<T> clazz) {
        return applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty(property, clazz);
    }

}
```

When your application starts, the static `applicationContext` field will be populated with your Application Context, so that you can use it afterwards from the static `getProperties` method.

You can then call it from a default method inside your repository, e.g.

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyDocument, String> {

    @Query(value = "{'myProperty': ?0}")
    List<MyDocument> findByMyProperty(int myProperty);

    default List<MyDocument> findByMyProperty() {
        final var myPropertyDefault = StaticPropertiesProvider.getProperty("my.property", Integer.class);
        return this.findByMyProperty(myProperty);
    }

}
```

Clearly there should be a property name `my.property` with an int value inside `application.properties`.

(you can do the same even with JPA repositories)